# NodeJS Pipe 443 already in use

Tags: node.js

I'm running an https server with [pagekite](http://pagekite.net/) and sometimes this error happens. Can someone explain to me what this is? I can't solve with *lsof* and *kill*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
netstat -an
```

in windows or

```
netstat -tulpn
```

in Linux to see if port 443 (https://) is taken by a process.

Comment: I can't reproduce error right now and this is probably lack of basic network knowledge, but: why is pipe instead of port?